# How to use custom functions in a React class after it was rendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say that I create additional functions in my React components, something like this:

```
class Cart extends React.Component {
    render() {
       return <div id="cart">My Cart Items</div>
    }
    getItem(id) {
       // magically return the item
    }
    addItem(id, name, type, price){
       // you get the idea
    }
}
```

Now, what is the best way to access `getItem` function from outside the class? For example, something that can be used as `window.Cart.getItem`. It seems to me that these functions are part of the `prototype` (non-initialized) of `nodeName` property of what `ReactDOM.render` returns.

What is the correct way for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

That's not really how react is supposed to be used.
What you are trying to do looks like MVC, and react is a completely different thing.

- a React component like your `<Cart>` receives props from its parent (could be the root `reactDOM.render()` or another react component)
- a React component may have internal and private method to retrieve additional data from elsewhere (but NOT from other react components)
- with these inputs (and only these inputs), the component knows what and how to render itself and possibly also children components to the DOM
- the stuff the component (or its children components) render may include interaction handlers (e.g. remove from cart button like `

  these interactions could fire an internal method inside the component

  and the internal method could call a method in a parent component, if it was passed down as a prop.

  or call some remote function to remove item from cart on server side.

In react terms, the `<Cart>` component is not the owner of the cart contents. It gets them as props, or retrieves them from somewhere else.
React really wants you to ONLY update the cart by passing a new set of props to the component to render.

You could try to shortcut react design by trying to expose any methods from the component to the outside world, but this goes against react design principles.
React has a one way data flow: a component gets props, and renders.

For reference, I can recommend [this page](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/06/05/why-react.html) on react principles.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a reference to the instance :)

```
<Cart ref={function(instance){ window.CartInstance = instance }} />

window.CartInstance.getItem(foo);
```

**ES6**

```
<Cart ref={(instance)=>window.CartInstance = instance} />

window.CartInstance.getItem(foo);
```

Comment: I do not think this would work: the instance with the methods is a javascript object in react's virtual DOM. This is not the same element as the HTML node in the real DOM. Even it would work, it is a very bad idea to break react's unidirectional dataflow like this.

Comment: It works as he wants, whether it's a smart architecturally is another point. 

He should really be looking at redux or flux in dealing with application state.

Comment: Didn't know that, but good to know (although I still think a "do should try this at home" advice is in order). Fully agree that flux or redux would be useful.

Comment: This actually worked. But because both of you suggested that it's not good architecturally, I'm going to look into Redux and Flux. Any other advice would be appreciated too.

Comment: And please forgive my ignorance, I'm just getting started with React

Comment: There's a free course on Redux from it's creator Dan Abramov on Egghead that you can check out: https://egghead.io/series/getting-started-with-redux. It can take a couple days to wrap your head around and get up and running depending on your experience but React + Redux is a very powerful combo for this kind of development.